# Best free website vulnerability scanners

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners

I need to check web security and vulnerability in my web application. Whatever free vulnerability scanners application or vulnerability scan online site's are available?

Comment: http://www.planetjake.net/image/data/stop-read-instructions.jpg Please refer to the FaQ.

Comment: Requests for lists do not fare well on this forum. That said, I provided an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be difficult to know which web app scanner is good, but there is a nearly famous researcher who came up with a way to benchmark various tools:

[SecToolAddict](http://sectooladdict.blogspot.ca/2012/07/2012-web-application-scanner-benchmark.html)

His findings point to:

- Arachni
- IronWASP
- Wapiti
- W3AF

As high-quality open source scanners.

PLEASE NOTE that no automated scanner can find everything and manual verification and testing also needs to be performed. Automated scanners are good for the "low-hanging fruit" but not for certifying that a site is 'safe'.